# Selenium Web Driver: not able to find the element on the 2nd page.

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and Firefox and Firebug
I am not able to locate the element on the second page. For example if I login to gmail then I am not able to locate and click on the sent items or any other button on the next page.

I tried with the xpath (both absolute and relative) but every time I am getting an error that element not found. 
with the code I am successfully able to login but as soon as the page loads I get an error "Element not Found".

Please suggest any solution

Comment: Gmail links are highly dynamic. But still, can you let us know the xpath or css path you have used for the element in second page?

Comment: I wouldn't try to automate testing on Google's pages, they are very complex, constantly change and thus make very bad locators. Are you just trying to check a user's email? There are many libraries out there to do that without needing a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are telling WebDriver to wait until the element on the 2nd page is loaded, WebDriver will simply try to click the element as soon as its able to run. This is bad because your element might not yet be loaded while WebDriver is already trying to click it... TIMEOUT mayhem ensues...

Try the following... use the WebDriverWait class to make WebDriver wait for the element on the page to be loaded before attempting to click it...:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your xpath")));
element.click();
```

The '100' in WebDriverWait(driver, 100) is the maximum amount of seconds you want WebDriver to  repeatedly attempt to locate the element before it times out...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by CODEBLACK. Also you can go for Imlicit wait,which would make selenium wait implicitly for a given period of time.
Try following:-
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

You can specify time as per your convenience.
Best O Luck. . .!